# How to deploy helm charts which are stored in AWS ECR using argoCD

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-ecr, argocd

I want to deploy helm charts, which are stored in a repository in AWS ECR, in the kubernetes cluster using ArgoCD. But I am getting a 401 unauthorized issue. I have pasted the entire issue below

```
Unable to create application: application spec is invalid: InvalidSpecError: Unable to get app details: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = `helm chart pull <aws account id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/testrepo:1.1.0` failed exit status 1: Error: unexpected status code [manifests 1.1.0]: 401 Unauthorized
```

Comment: did you add helm repo?
https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_repo_add/

Comment: How are you storing helm charts in ECR? I thought ECR only stored docker images.

Comment: @jordanm check this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/push-oci-artifact.html

Comment: @RtmY pretty cool, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use ECR for storing helm charts (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/push-oci-artifact.html)

I have managed to add the repo to ArgoCD, but the token expires so it is not a complete solution.

```
argocd repo add XXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com --type helm --name some-helmreponame --enable-oci --username AWS --password $(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the declarative repository definition (see https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#repositories, or just override `.argo-cd.configs.repositories` in the Helm chart) it is actually quite easy to create a cron-job that updates the ECR credentials:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: argocd-ecr-credentials
spec:
  schedule: '0 */6 * * *' # every 6 hours, since credentials expire every 12 hours
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      name: argocd-ecr-credentials
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: argocd-server
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          containers:
            - name: update-secret
              image: alpine/k8s # Anything that contains kubectl + aws cli
              command:
                - /bin/bash
                - "-c"
                - |
                  PASSWORD=$(aws ecr get-login-password --region [your aws region] | base64 -w 0)
                  kubectl patch secret -n argocd argocd-repo-[name of your repository] --type merge -p "{\"data\": {\"password\": \"$PASSWORD\"}}"
```

ArgoCD repository secrets are usually called `argocd-repo-*` suffixed with the key of the repository entry in the values.yaml.

This will start a pod every 6 hours to do an ECR login and update the secret in kubernetes, that contains the repository definition for ArgoCD.

Make sure to use the argocd-server service account (or create your own) since the container will not be able to modify the secret otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experimenting with the following (Not yet complete)

Create a secret for an AWS IAM role that allows you to get an ECR login password.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: aws-ecr-get-login-password-creds
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/secret-type: repository
stringData:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: <Fill In>
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: <Fill In>
```

Now create an ArgoCD workflow that either runs every 12 hours or runs on PreSync Hook (Completely untested, will try to keep this updated, anyone can update this for me).

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: aws-ecr-get-login-password-
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PreSync
spec:
  entrypoint: update-ecr-login-password
  templates:

    # This is what will run.
    # First the awscli
    # Then the resource creation using the stdout of the previous step
    - name: update-ecr-login-password
      steps:
        - - name: awscli
            template: awscli
        - - name: argocd-ecr-credentials
            template: argocd-ecr-credentials
            arguments:
              parameters:
              - name: password
                value: "{{steps.awscli.outputs.result}}"

    # Create a container that has awscli in it
    # and run it to get the password using `aws ecr get-login-password`
    - name: awscli
      script:
        image: amazon/aws-cli:latest
        command: [bash]
        source: |
          aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1
        # We need aws secrets that can run `aws ecr get-login-password`
        envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: aws-ecr-get-login-password-creds

    # Now we can create the secret that has the password in it
    - name: argocd-ecr-credentials
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: password
      resource:
        action: create
        manifest: |
          apiVersion: v1
          kind: Secret
          metadata:
            name: argocd-ecr-credentials
            namespace: argocd
            labels:
              argocd.argoproj.io/secret-type: repository
          stringData:
            url: 133696059149.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
            username: AWS
            password: {{inputs.parameters.password}}
```

Comment: You are running Argo Workflows alongside ArgoCD to run this workflow, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the external-secrets controller as describe in the article:

https://developer.harness.io/docs/continuous-delivery/gitops/oci-support/helm-oci-repository-aws-ecr/

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587